# Get Entire List<String> from map in Drools

Tags: drools

I need to get entire List from hashmap in Drools.I have inserted hashmap as fact in working memory. In the when part i need to get the list from hashmap.I am using drools 7 version

Map contains String,List of Strings

Please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Most of Drools rules use MVEL syntax on when part. According to [MVEL Language Guyide](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Transwiki:MVEL_Language_Guide#Map_Access):

```
user["foobar"]
```

is the equivalent of the Java code:

```
user.get("foobar");
```